# I am trying to append a div on each element with class name preview-card-body. It appends but not implemented as a HTML code and appears as a string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arraylist

I am trying to append a div on each element with class name preview-card-body.

```
for(let q=0;q<$(".preview-card-body").length ; q++)
{
    $(".preview-card-body")[q].append(`<div class="input-group mt-2">
    <div class="input-group-text">Correct Answer</div>
    <div class="form-control">1</div>
    </div>`)
}
```

But it appends as a string not as a HTML code and shows a preview like this

```
<div class="input-group mt-2"> <div class="input-group-text">Correct Answer</div> <div class="form-control">2</div> </div>
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Beacuse you're using the native [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) method instead of jQuery [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content). `$(".preview-card-body")[q]` returns an actual DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Ok i got that. How to do it then?

Comment: Please think faster than you write ...

Comment: Ok. Is it better to give each preview-card-body a unique id, then apply it. I have solved this problem that way but I thought there must be some other way

Comment: You're seriously asking how to wrap the returned element into `$` call to get a jQuery object, which will contain the correct append method which can append a string as HTML instead of plain text???

Comment: I just have to write $(".preview-card-body")[q] in $

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate through the array of elements having class `preview-card-body`. You can simply do this as follows

```
$(".preview-card-body").append(`<div class="input-group mt-2">
    <div class="input-group-text">Correct Answer</div>
    <div class="form-control">1</div>`)
```

It will automatically append the html in every element with the class in question i.e. `preview-card-body`.

Here is a running code sample for you.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var content = `<div class="input-group mt-2">
    <div class="input-group-text">Correct Answer</div>
    <div class="form-control">1</div>
    </div>`;
  $(".preview-card-body").append(content)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="preview-card-body"></div>
<div class="preview-card-body"></div>
<div class="preview-card-body"></div>
<div class="preview-card-body"></div>
<div class="preview-card-body"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Append</button>
```